# Search for a String and replace it

Tags: powershell-3.0

New to Powershell.

Suppose the following text is inside a file called "example.txt".

```
------------
example.txt
------------
#   Chicago                9057
111111111111111111000000000111111111111
000020330000000009999993124442222224244
#
#
#   Michigan               7050
908798888888888888888888888222222222222
948781467463484635000558755551656666666
#
```

- How do I write a Scirpt to open this file - example.txt and search for "Chicago" or "Michigan" and based on that - replace the number "9057" or "7050" to "9059" or "7051" respectively?

  Would appreciate any help.
  -Thanks,
  Matt

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Hi Jeff, fair enough....I will try to add more stuff that I am trying to do....